# Suppose a and b are the solutions to the quadratic equation $2x^2-3x-6=0$. Find the value of $(a+2)(b+2)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Please explain and help. Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far, or what are some ideas you might have for this problem?

Comment: Hint: Vieta relations, one of them is $a+b=\frac{3}{2}$.  You can also read off the product $ab$ of the roots from the equation.

Comment: I know I am supposed to use vietas but how?

Answer (score 3):

Using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), we have:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
a+b &=& -\frac{-3}{2} = \frac{3}{2}\\
ab &=& \frac{-6}{2} = -3
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(a+2)(b+2) &=& ab + 2a + 2b + 4\\
&=& ab + 2(a+b) + 4\\
&=& -3 + 2(\frac{3}{2}) + 4\\
&=& 4
\end{eqnarray}
$$